# php shell_exec adds unwanted line break

Tags: php, shell, shell-exec

Why does `php`'s `shell_exec` command add an unwanted line break (\r\n) to the output and how can I prevent that?

test.php:

```
<?php
var_dump(shell_exec('echo "test"'));
```

running `php test.php` results in:

```
string(5) "test
"
```

Comment: why in the world are you doing an echo with shell_exec ? are you planning on changing that to something else later ?

Comment: @DanyKhalife: It's just a simplified example.

Comment: ok the reason i asked, is that you the problem you are facing is due to the use of `echo` and is not always the case for all commands (at least from what i know, not all of the commands have a -n option that works the same way, and some do not even output a newline at all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `-n` as argument to your `echo` command, this will prevent `echo` from outputting a trailing newline.

From the manual:

> -n do not output the trailing newline

Answer (score 3):

The `echo` command adds the line break so your example works as expected. If you want to remove it just use [`trim`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

```
var_dump(trim(shell_exec('echo "test"')));
```

This will output:

```
string(5) "test"
```

Comment: I've been doing this (trim) before but it is problematic when the echoed string ends on a line break.

Comment: @Cicada not every command has such a `-n` flag but you are right.

Comment: @Horen, Did you try executing it within back-ticks? What happens then?

Comment: @Cthulhu Did you mean like this? `var_dump(shell_exec('echo \'test\''));` that doesn't work

Comment: `echo -n "test"` works perfectly. Thanks, @Cicada. Can you add it as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @Horen, I meant backticks instead of shell_exec. I think it will be identical though. [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)